# Binding Data from table to repeater in front End

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, repeater

I have a table where I want to bind the data from the table into repeater. But I am unable to start how to get this. Here is my design HTML. I need it in the repeater.

I want to show something like [this](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=16142329248612)

And my HTML for that is somethig like below:-

```
<div class="Newsdivalign">
                <div id="testMsg" class="popup">
                    <div class="popup-container">
                        <div class="popup-content">
                            <div class="popup-close js-popup-close modal-close">X</div>
                            <div>
                                <p class="popup-para">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</p>
                            </div>
                            <div style="padding: 7px;">
                                <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST</p>
                                <p class="SStorypara">
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                                    the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                                    of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                                    also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                                    recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                    Ipsum.
                                </p>
                                <p class="SStorypara">
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                                    the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                                    of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                                    also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                                    recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                    Ipsum.
                                </p>
                                <p class="SStorypara">
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                                    the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                                    of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                                    also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                                    recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                    Ipsum.
                                </p>
                                <p class="SStorypara">
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                                    the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                                    of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                                    also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                                    recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                    Ipsum.
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>





                </div>
                <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="#testMsg" class="modal-popup">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span>&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span> </p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                </div>


                <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="Div1">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more </p>
                </div>
                <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="#">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span>&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="#">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="#">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span>&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="#">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="#">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span>&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="#">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="#">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span>&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Newsdiv">
                    <p class="Newspara"><a href="#">Recognised by the World Economic Forum as a Global Growth Company, 2014</a></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate">News Posted: Jan 15, 2015 – 05:08 PM EST &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span>&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span></p>
                    <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                </div>
                <div class="pagination clearfix">
                    <a href="#">First</a>
                    &nbsp;<a href="#">«</a>

                    <a href="#">1</a>
                    <strong>2</strong>
                    <a href="#">3</a>

                    <a href="#">»</a>
                    &nbsp;<a href="#">Last</a>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Please help

Updated code of mine:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptNews" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="Newsdiv">
                        <p class="Newspara"><a href="#"><%#Eval("title")%></a></p>
                        <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:-

```
public void bindRepeater()
{
    DataTable dtInfo = new DataTable();
    dtInfo.Columns.Add("title");
    DataRow dr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        dr = dtInfo.NewRow();
        dr["title"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        dtInfo.Rows.Add(dr);

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to display records fetched from a database using some templates?

Comment: @elf: Yes I want to display records using databse

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379545/what-is-the-best-reusable-dry-clean-etc-way-to-store-and-show-data-possibl/28379651#28379651, I have just answered a question similar to this.

Comment: @elf: It is showing me edit section. Give me the proper link. Now I got that

Comment: let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: @elf: It is not related to what I want.. I want to get the data into repeater, As I have mentioned in images.. Also. See `<asp:Repeater ID="rptNews" runat="server" class="popup-container" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Repeater>` Now what else is required to make it customize according to what I showed in the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70452/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-elf).

Comment: oh sorry, I missed it by miles. I din't see the tags. Anyways have a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp . If you have trouble in understanding the code, let me know

Comment: what action do you  want on - "click here to know more"?

Answer (score -1):

try this.place this repeater to your design.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptNews" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <div class="Newsdiv">
                <p class="Newspara"><a href="#"><%#Eval("News_Title")%></a></p>
                <p class="NewsDate">News Posted:<%#Eval("News_Time")%> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span>&nbsp;<span class="label">NGO1</span></p>
                <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
            </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

and get data from your database according to that. here i am creating demo datatable to bind static data in repeater. you can change it to your database data.

```
public void bindRepeater()
{
       DataTable dtInfo = new DataTable();
       dtInfo.Columns.Add("News_Title");
       dtInfo.Columns.Add("News_Time");
       DataRow dr;
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
           dr = dtInfo.NewRow();
           dr["News_Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
           dr["News_Title"] = "Recongition statement";
           dtInfo.Rows.Add(dr);
      }
      rptNews.DataSource = dtInfo;
      rptNews.DataBind();

}


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bindRepeater();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Jignesh, the title will come from the table,it will change

Comment: can you show your code? what you have done? so i can figure it out

Comment: sorry i missed to update my code... now see the updated code in method i.e. "bindRepeater()".

Comment: No it is not working, I tried a bit different way.!!

Comment: can you saw me your code?. so  i can identify the error